# What is the difference between Item.Id and EmailMessage.InternetMessageId

Tags: exchange-server, exchangewebservices

Whats the difference between [EmailMessage.InternetMessageId](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.emailmessage.internetmessageid(v=exchg.80).aspx) and [Item.Id](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.item.id(v=exchg.80).aspx)
provided EmailMessage inherits from Item. Which one of these is serverid of the email message which is bound to change if the folder of the email changes?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Internet Message Id is assigned by the sending MTA (Message Transfer agent) and is a part of the RFC spec see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message-ID. The ItemId is the Store identifier that EWS uses to access items see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn605828(v=exchg.150).aspx for more details.

> > Which one of these is serverid of the email message which is bound to change if the folder of the email changes?

The EWSId will changes if an Item is moved or copied between folders the Internet messageId won't but its not guaranteed unique.